# How to make a colorful shadow using css

Tags: html, css

want to make colorful shadows to buttons using CSS with root color
notes that I know ways on google but I need something special for my web bage

want to be experienced with CSS and sass

Comment: Could you show us code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we all have different interests and desires in life, and not sure whether what I call beautiful would really be beautiful in your eyes, perhaps this seems simple and beautiful button shadow design.

## #1

**Sample Html Code**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Sample CSS styles**

```
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  width: 140px;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  }

.button:hover {
  background-color: #2EE59D;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px rgba(46, 229, 157, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}
```

Check a [live demo here](https://codepen.io/seme332/pen/reJOwo)

If you want to make it fancy or better, see more [here](https://getcssscan.com/css-box-shadow-examples)

## #2

Sample **badge** with simple and good design:

HTML

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="badges"><br>
      <p>
          <span class="firstLine">GET UP TO</span><br>
          <span class="secondLine">$10,000</span><br>
          <span class="thirdLine">PER MONTH</span><br>
          <span class="fourthLine">AS A STARTER</span>
      </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:#ecf0f1;}

a{text-decoration:none;}

.firstLine {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
}.secondLine {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
} .thirdLine {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 300;
}.fourthLine {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}

.badges {
    position:relative;
    margin:140px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius:100%;
    color: #552F87;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite running swing;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite running swing;
    -o-animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite running swing;
    animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite running swing;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100px -71px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100px -71px;
    -o-transform-origin: 100px -71px;
    transform-origin: 100px -71px;
}
.badges:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;left:99px;
    width:2px;height:81px;
    border-radius:0%;
    background:#000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(5deg);}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(5deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes swing{
    0%{-o-transform:rotate(5deg);}
    50%{-o-transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    100%{-o-transform:rotate(5deg);}
}

@keyframes swing{
    0%{transform:rotate(5deg);}
    50%{transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    100%{transform:rotate(5deg);}
}
```

Demo [here](https://codepen.io/Namwanza/pen/abKEGrZ)

Another badge demo [here](https://codepen.io/azedo/pen/nggZJW)